# How can I zip 2 lists (key list and value list) together and insert into a mongoDB collection? c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, visual-studio

I have 2 lists that I want to zip together and then insert into a database. I have the following code but I'm not quite sure what's wrong with it.

```
        MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
        var db = dbClient.GetDatabase("TestDB");
        var collec = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("TestDB");

            var keysAndVals = keys.Zip(vals, (first, second) => first + 
                ":" + second);
            IList<String> kv = keysAndVals.ToList();
            BsonArray bArray = new BsonArray();
            foreach (var term in kv)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(term);
                    bArray.Add(term);
                }
            var document = new BsonDocument();
            document.Add(kv);
            collec.InsertOneAsync(document);
```

I would like to use this to insert transaction information to my database.